# About the linearity of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a complex vector space. Let $Y$ be a dense subspace of $X$. Let $\phi:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a map such that $\phi$ is linear and bounded on $Y$. Can we say that $\phi$ is linear or continuous ?
Hahn Banach theorem only talks about the *existence* of a unique extension, it may not be the same map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Define a function $f$ that takes $0$ on $Y$ and a constant non-zero vector on $X \setminus Y$. Then $f$ is neither continuous or linear.

Comment: Can you tell me by adding what minimal condition will $\phi$ become linear or continuous?

Comment: I don't know about being minimal, but if you assume $f$ is continuous on $X$ (not just $Y$), then $f$ must be linear.

Comment: Thank you. If I add the condition that $\phi$ is homogeneous on $X$ i.e $\phi(\alpha x)=\alpha\phi(x)$ for $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ and $x\in X$. Will it help?

Comment: No, for example, instead of making $f$ a constant non-zero vector, try making it the identity map on $X \setminus Y$. That will be homogeneous, but not additive.

Comment: But the identity map does not map $X\setminus Y$ to $\mathbb{C}$.....